# Best and the quickest way to place variable sized photographs into canvas with no gaps

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-fireworks

I have 46 images and have to put them inside a 300cm×120cm canvas. All the image files have different sizes. Is there any tool or method or technique to place them onto the canvas without gapping (at least minimized way)?

Is there any approach like "biggest images in the center, smaller ones on the edges" or vice versa?

I think this could be an optimization problem and someone over there could have solved this problem.

Comment: I would suggest using Abode Photoshop Contact Sheets. See tutorial here http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-photoshop-cs6/creating-contact-sheets/. I don't think you can order from biggest in the center.

Comment: This sort of thing is known as a "packing problem", and you're looking for "optimal rectangle packing". There isn't a simple solution, but that might help you search for some ways to go about it. One of the most common ones is basically what you've already thought of - start with the biggest one and work down from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to place images on a canvas, it would be better to use layout software like Adobe InDesign. 
The following method is the easiest way to place multiple images simultaneously.
Create a new file in InDesign

- In the dialogue box, untick 'facing pages'and enter the dimensions of the document you require
- In the 'gutter' field enter 0 (so that there will be no gapping between images when placed – images will butt against each other)
- Hit 'OK', and select File > Place
- Browse for images. Select adjacent files by holding 'Shift' and clicking. Select non-adjacent files by holding Cmd or Ctrl and clicking. Then hit 'Open' (This loads the cursor with your images.
- Click and drag from the top-left corner of your document, but before releasing the mouse hit the right arrow to create multiple picture frames. Click the down arrow to create rows of picture frames.
- Release the mouse when you have enough frames and they will fill with the images you selected.
- To fit your images to their frames, select Object > Fitting > Fill Frames Proportionally
- You can export as PDF, which you can optimise later in Photoshop if required.
- This creates multiple, equally sized images that butt against each other.